# Align divs vertically with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been working on this for hours, and I just can't figure it out,

Let's say I have a lot of divs with floating around, with jquery `draggable` attached to them so, their position keeps changing all the time.

Now I want to be able to space them out vertically, so the space between each div would be the same, one of the biggest issue is that each div's height also keeps changing.

Each time I try to do it right i just write ~100 lines of code I just get lost in confusion, maybe there is some easy way to do it, by the way, here is example of how it looks like, I didn't include any of my written code since it doesn't make much sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/M6PmM/

Comment: Do you want to keep the same vertical space during the drag event?

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy no that should only happen once a `button` is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting to see the different interpretations of your question. When I think of aligning vertically, I think of Adobe Illustrator, and how you can evenly space a number of selected shapes. To that end, you could so something like this:

NOTE: this could easily be adapted to maintain an even gap between the elements, regardless of their individual heights.

```
$('.align').click(function() {

    // Cache the elements
    var $obj = $('.obj');

    // Sort them by offset top
    $obj = $obj.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).offset().top - $(b).offset().top;
    });

    // Get get the offset of the first and last elements
    // NOTE that we included the last element's height... you may need to tweak it
    // here due to CSS borders adding to the height
    var firstOffsetTop = $obj.first().offset().top;
    var lastOffsetTop = $obj.last().offset().top + $obj.last().height();

    // The new container height is the difference between the first,
    // and last element's position
    var containerHeight = lastOffsetTop - firstOffsetTop;

    // Determine the gap between each element, based on the height of the container
    // divided by the number of elements
    var spacing = containerHeight / $obj.length;

    // Assign top properties
    $obj.each(function(i, el) {
        $(this).css('top', (i * spacing) + firstOffsetTop + 'px');
    });

});
```

Comment: wow, that's really close to what i want, if you could please make it so the lowest and the highest div would stay at where it is, and others div in the middle would align according to those two divs

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer. There's a slight 1-2 pixel shift that's most likely caused by the CSS borders adding to the height/offset, but I'm sure you'll figure that out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Late but this could be another way to do:

```
$('.align').click(function(){

    var t = 0;
    var dist = 10;

    $('.obj').each(function(i,e){

        t += $('.obj').eq(i-1).height() + dist;

        $(this).animate({

            left: $('.container').offset().left + dist,
            top: t

         }, 500);

    });

});
```